# Visual Studio Online, Github, Jira, Octopus Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, github, version-control, jira, azure-devops

We are looking at using Visual Studio online in an environment with multiple development partners that support a myriad number of systems. Across these partners, each one of them uses their own source control however we are looking at a model that commits code into a repository managed by us.

As part of this, we are looking to support partners that use toolsets such as Github, Jira, Bamboo, TeamCity, Octopus Deploy, etc

- Does Visual Studio Online natively integrate with all of these?
- When using Visual Studio Online, do accounts need to be setup with each of these services e.g Github?
- Will Visual Studio Online support all IDEs e.g. Eclipse, Xcode, etc?
- What other considerations do we need to consider e.g. latency, local copies (should connectivity be lost), etc?
- If upgrading from Team Foundation Server 2010 to Visual Studio Online, what other considerations do we have to take onboard?
- For the purposes of continuous integration & deployment, does Visual Studio Online support this natively?
- If there is no native support for Jira for example, are there similar native features available with Visual Studio Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want integration with GitHub, then the first requirement would be to use Git as your VCS. This also requires you to use Team Foundation Server 2013 (or later) if you want to host it yourself, as earlier versions don’t support Git.

Once you use Git, you can indeed access the repository from VSO with other clients, as it provides a normal Git interface which all Git tooling options can talk to. And you also get the benefits of Git as a DVCS, so you can use it completely offline.

If you want to user other online services (e.g. GitHub), then of course you do need accounts for those services. VSO is something separate on its own.

As for features of VSO, you need to know that it’s technically a Team Foundation Server, so it comes with a range of included tools. For example an issue management, a build server with continuous integration, a team chat room, etc. So you may not need other services.

Comment: Thanks poke. The understanding i have is that there is no requirement to use a service such as Github for the purposes of Git. Git is from what i have been told (Microsoft), is natively built into Visual Studio Online.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio Online, just like Team Foundation Server 2013 or later, has built-in support for Git repositories. So yes, you could probably manage most (if not all) your development work on VSO alone.

Comment: Is there any benefit in using Github as the repository outside of Visual Studio Online? It is my understanding that if used natively, all the capabilities such as issue management, etc are available however if you use an external repository and leverage Visual Studio Online as a portal, you lose these capabilities.

Comment: Would you know if there are any costs to use the integrations available with VSO i.e. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/vso-integrations-directory-vs.aspx?

Comment: Would you know how difficult if at all it is to migrate from Team Foundation Server 2010 to Visual Studio Online?

Comment: Well, you can publish Git repositories to multiple external hosters. So you could use one as the primary remote, and then maintain clones on several hosts (GitHub, BitBucket, or your own private server in your basement). There is not really a restriction. As far as GitHub’s features go, usually, you would want to avoid spreading the management utilities to multiple services. So when you use VSO, you already have issue management etc., so doing it also on GitHub would probably be less productive (either you split the data up, or you replicate it; both means more work, you probably don’t need).

Comment: Those integrations are usually free on the VSO side; but most of those services come with their own costs (or restrictions if you use it for free). So you would have to check the service you are interested in for its costs. But integrating it with your VSO will then probably be free. As for migrating TFS to VSO, check [these instructions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/migrate-team-projects-vs); there is an actual migration tool available that should make it rather simple.

Comment: I hope you don't mind having a quick chat. I do have a few more questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86913/discussion-between-motivated-and-poke).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Online ([now Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx)) supports Eclipse, IntelliJ, [your favorite Java IDE](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/java-vs), Xcode, Visual Studio, or [any editor/IDE you like](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs).